# Libreoffice basic - Associative array

Tags: libreoffice, basic, libreoffice-basic

I come from PHP/JS/AS3/... this kind languages. Now I'm learning basic for Libreoffice and I'm kind of struggling to find how to get something similar as associative array I use to use with others languages.

What I'm trying to do is to have this kind structure:

2016 => October => afilename.csv

2016 => April => anotherfilename.csv

with the year as main key, then the month and some datas.
More I try to find informations and more I confuse, so if someone could tell me a little bit about how to organise my datas I would be so pleased.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As @Chrono Kitsune said, Python and Java have such features but Basic does not.  Here is a [Python-UNO](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python) example for LibreOffice Writer:

```py
def dict_example():
    files_by_year = {
        2016 : {'October' : 'afilename.csv',
                'November' : 'bfilename.csv'},
        2017 : {'April' : 'anotherfilename.csv'},
    }
    doc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    oVC = doc.getCurrentController().getViewCursor()
    for year in files_by_year:
        for month in files_by_year[year]:
            filename = files_by_year[year][month]
            oVC.getText().insertString(
                oVC, "%s %d: %s\n" % (month, year, filename), False)

g_exportedScripts = dict_example,
```

Create a file with the code above using a text editor such as Notepad or GEdit.  Then place it [here](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python_as_a_macro_language#Script_Location).

To run it, open Writer and go to `Tools -> Macros -> Run Macro`, and find the file under `My Macros`.

Answer (score 1):

This question was asked a long ago, but answers are only half correct.

It is true that LibreOffice Basic does not have a native associative array type. But the LibreOffice API provides services. The [`com.sun.star.container.EnumerableMap`](https://api.libreoffice.org/docs/idl/ref/servicecom_1_1sun_1_1star_1_1container_1_1EnumerableMap.html) service will meet your needs.

Here's an example:

```
' Create the map
map = com.sun.star.container.EnumerableMap.create("long", "any")

' The values
values = Array( _
    Array(2016, "October", "afilename.csv"), _
    Array(2016, "April", "anotherfilename.csv") _
)

' Fill the map
For i=LBound(values) to UBound(values)
    value = values(i)
    theYear = value(0)
    theMonth = value(1)
    theFile = value(2)
    If map.containsKey(theYear) Then
        map2 = map.get(theYear)
    Else
        map2 = com.sun.star.container.EnumerableMap.create("string","string")
        map.put(theYear, map2)
    End If
    map2.put(theMonth, theFile)
Next

' Access to an element
map.get(2016).get("April")  ' anotherfilename.csv
```

As you see, the methods are similar to what you can find in more usual languages.

Beware: if you experience `IllegalTypeException` you might have to use `CreateUNOValue("<type>", ...)` to cast a value into the declared type. (See this very old issue https://bz.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=121192 for an example.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with LibreOffice (or OpenOffice.org) BASIC or VBA, but I haven't found anything in the documentation for any sort of associative array, hash, or whatever else someone calls it.

However, many modern BASIC dialects allow you to [define your own type as a series of fields](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/BASIC_Guide/Other_Instructions#Type...End_Type). Then it's just a matter of using something like

```
Dim SomeArray({count|range}) As New MyType
```

I think that's as close as you'll get without leveraging outside libraries. Maybe the [Python-UNO bridge](http://www.openoffice.org/udk/python/python-bridge.html) would help since Python has such a feature (dictionaries), but I wouldn't know for certain. I also don't know how it would impact performance. You might prefer Java instead of Python for interfacing with UNO, and that's okay too: there's the [`java.util.HashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) type. Sorry I can't help more, but the important thing to remember is that any BASIC code in tends to live up to the meaning of the word "basic" in English without external assistance.